# Why is html5 postMessage not working for me?

Tags: html, postmessage

I use a few lines of javascript to create an iframe element, and then I'd like to send it a message, like this:

```
function loadiframe (callback) {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = 'iframe';
    iframe.seamless = 'seamless';
    iframe.src = 'http://localhost:3000/iframe.html';
    body.appendChild(iframe);
    callback();
}

loadiframe(function() {
    cpframe = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow;
    cpframe.postMessage('please get this message','http://localhost:3000');
    console.log('posted');
})
```

And then, inside http://localhost:3000/iframe.html (the source of the iframe) is something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>does not work</title>
<script>
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(event) {
  if (event.origin == "http://localhost:3000") {
    document.write(JSON.stringify(event));
    document.write(typeof event);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But nothing happens... I even tried to not use the safety check for origin, but even like that nothing happens... Like it never got the message...

Am I in some kind of async problem ? I tried to make sure the iframe was loaded before the postMessage went away...

EDIT1: Also, no errors show on the console...

EDIT2: I tried it in Google Chrome 11 and Firefox 4

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possible problems:

1. You're calling `callback` before the child frame has loaded - try it in the `load` event or do it in a `setTimeout`
2. I've never managed to get `postMessage` to work with anything other that '*' as the origin.  If I put a URL in there I get a security warning "Security Error: Content at http://xxx/ may not load data from http://yyy/", except only in the error console (Ctrl + Shift + J) not in any other place.  I suspect there's some other stuff that needs set up somewhere for that to work, but I've not yet figured out what.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/Bh8jB/) with a slightly modified version of your code loading a document off my domain, works for me in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks robertc, it works with a setTimeout and I didn't have to set '*' as the origin (yay for safety). Now I think I'll make the iframe send a message to the parent window telling it the iframe is ready, and then the window will send the message. Do you think it's the right way to proceed ?

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo That sounds like it would work, it's like a registration event for the `iframe`.

Comment: Not sure why that parameter is called "origin", because it's actually the URL of the destination that you have to fill in as the second parameter of `postMessage`. So if you're sending a message to an `<iframe />`, you literally have to call: `iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({data}, iframe.src);`

Answer (score 0):

One problem that occured in our test setup was the fact that the hosting test site where the iFrame was placed was served via the file system. So we switched to Apache to serve it via localhost.

The application inside the iFrame was an Angular application: The event handler for receiving events from window.parent was bind inside the Angular applications ngOnInit method. That also was not working. It was needed to attach the event handler inside a script block in index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late but for the future sake...

When you are posting a message from an Iframe, the origin is not the iframe's domain but the parent's (target origin).

Example: Parent's domain is `http://parent.local` and Iframe is `http://iframe.local`

To post from the IFrame to the parent and **only the valid parent**:

```
window.parent.postMessage({foo: 12}, 'http://parent.local') // note the domain. we want to talk to only that domain / target origin
```

The parent can confirm that the request came from a valid iframe by checking the origin property on the MessageEvent

```
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
 console.log(event.origin) // will be http://iframe.local
})
```