# postMessage() generates error "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, postmessage

I'm trying to get `postMessage()` to work to communicate between an iframe and my main website. However using the exact syntax given in the [example code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage#Example) on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage), I am being presented with a nice `Undefined is not a function` error. I've tried several things, such as initializing the iframe inside Javascript and appending it to my page, but that left me with the same error. Same for have seperate selectors to select my iframe.

I have the following Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.editor').postMessage("A", "domain here");
    });

    function receiveMessage(event)
    {
        if (event.origin !== "domain here")
            return;

        // Do something
    }

    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
</script>
```

The script above tries to send a message to my iframe on the page, which looks like:

```
<iframe src="domain here/frameListener.html" class="editor"></iframe>
```

It then has a function `receiveMessage` to catch any messages being send as a response to the main webpage. Last but not least, I've tried the answers given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030262/why-is-html5-postmessage-not-working-for-me): But that did not fix my problem. It is therefore not a duplicate.

How can I get rid of this error message?

Comment: `postMessage` is a method of `Window` object, whereas `$('.editor')` is a jQuery object

Comment: @hindmost Thanks, I've changed my code to the example given in Jivings answer, however that did not fix my issue.

Comment: Incredible! Lost hours with bad MDN example... Thanks for the question and asnswer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`postMessage` is not a jQuery function so you need to get the actual `window` DOM element and call it on that:

```
 $('.editor').get(0).contentWindow.postMessage("A", "domain here");
```

Furthermore, you need to access the `contentWindow` property of the `iframe`. Here is an excerpt from the MDN docs:

> ```
> otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
> ```
>
> `otherWindow`
>
> A reference to another window; such a reference may be
> obtained, for example, using the contentWindow property of an iframe
> element, the object returned by window.open, or by named or numeric
> index on window.frames.

Comment: So you cannot select an element using `JQuery` at all, if you want to use Javascript methods? That is lame :/ Thanks for answering! Will test it and accept your answer.

Comment: I'm left with the same error message after changing my code to your example, unfortunately.

Comment: @KevinVoorn Updated. You need to access the `contentWindow` property

Comment: Yep, that did the tricks. Thank you, been struggling with this forever, haha. So if I understand correctly, you cannot use Javascript methods on JQuery selected objects?

Comment: @KevinVoorn jQuery exposes it's own API to selected elements. Think of the Object returned by jQuery as a wrapper for DOM elements. In order to call the normal DOM functions on each of them you need to `get` them out of the wrapper.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I will accept your answer in 3 minutes.