# Pause Youtube video on bootstrap tab click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, youtube-api, video.js

I am having multiple youtube videos inside Bootstrap tab content. I intend to pause on click event of Bootstrap tab. 
What I coded is :

```
function stopIframeonTabClick(){

$('.video-nav-tab a').click(function (e) {

 var selected = $(this).parent().index();

  $('.video-nav-tab a').each(function(index){

 if(index != selected){

   var iframe = $(".tab-content").children().eq(index).find('iframe');

   //console.log(iframe.attr('class'));

   var data = {"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""};
   var message = JSON.stringify(data);
   $("iframe", index)[0].contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');

   }
    });
});
};//stopIframeonTabClick()

stopIframeonTabClick();
```

It is not working and I find  console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined
```

I am sure `$("iframe", index)[0].contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');` the index is doing wrong here, but I can't figure out what to do.

Also checked in IE, where the video is not playing even due to the error.

Basically I am using [youtube-video.js](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube) to play the video inside a [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and wrapped inside bootstrap tab contents

I would be highly obliged if anyone can help me to sort it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `stopIframeonTabClick` adds new `click` event every time it's executed. Click events stacks, not replaces eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long R&D I have done it. What I was mistaking the picking up the actual iframe in the active tab-contents and active slick slider. What I need to have the actual `window` DOM. Thanks to Jivings in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211384/postmessage-generates-error-undefined-is-not-a-function)

I am sharing the code for future help to others:-

```
 $(window).load(function(){

    function stopIframeonTabClick(){

    $('.video-nav-tab a').click(function (e) {

    var selected = $(this).parent().index();

    $('.video-nav-tab a').each(function(index){

    if(index != selected){

    var iframe = $(".video-tab-content.tab-content .tab-pane.active .slick-active .video-wrapper ").find('iframe');
       var iframeID = iframe.attr('id');
      console.log(iframeID); 
       var data = {"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""};
       var message = JSON.stringify(data);
        $('#'+iframeID )[0].contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');

          }
         });
        });
     };//stopIframeonTabClick()

 stopIframeonTabClick();
});
```